# SSRS - html <hr /> not interpreted on rendering

Tags: reporting-services

I have an application storing html in a sql table, of which i need a report to consume and display. The text placeholder is set to 'HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles' and all html is indeed interpreted well, except for the '<'hr /'>' tags.
[image]
[image]
Blacking out data...
App:
[image]
Stored html:
[image]
SSRS output:
[image]

The html horizontal line breaks are the only tags not being recognized by SSRS.
Has anyone else encountered this?

I apologize in advanced if this has been answered before, as i could not find a related post. Also, could not find any kind of documentation on compatibility. I've tried several output formatting and played around with various setting with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: <hr /> tag is not supported in ssrs report html rendering . see this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS only supports a very limited set of HTML tags and `<HR/>` isn't one of them.

Try separating your text into paragraphs instead using `<P>` and `</P>`.

From [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx), the list of supported tags are:

- Hyperlinks: `<A HREF>`
- Fonts: `<FONT>`
- Header, style and block elements: `<H{n}>`, `<DIV>`, `<SPAN>`, `<P>`, `<HN>`
- Text format: `<B>`, `<I>`, `<U>`, `<S>`
- List handling: `<OL>`, `<UL>`, `<LI>`